# Migration from Bitcoin wallet (Schildbach) to bitcoin core

Tags: wallet

Is there a standard way of migrating from Bitcoin Wallet (Schildbach) to Bitcoin Core?

I understand that backups are not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script seems to do the work

https://github.com/jleni/wallet-decrypt

You just need to create a backup and it will give you back a mnemonic that you can use in electrum or electrum cash.

Answer (score 1):

Just get an address from Bitcoin Core and make a transaction which sends all of your Bitcoin from the Schildbach wallet to the address from Bitcoin Core.

Comment: I see two problems there: 1. A small cost. 2. Very risky in the next weeks...

Comment: There is no other easy or standard way. The only other way is to retrieve the schildbach wallet's wallet file, and, IIRC, your phone will need to be rooted. Then you will need to use Bitcoinj's wallet tool in order to dump the private keys. Once you have the private keys, you can import them into Core. But that whole process takes a lot of work and is difficult to do.